# Find index number of the number closest to 32 in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void closestNumber(){
  int a[] = {-1, 58, 32, 16, 54};
  int current=a[0];
  int diff=Maths.abs(32-current);
  int index=0;

  for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    int newDiff= Maths.abs(32-a[i]);
    if (newDiff< diff){
    index=i;
    }
    System.out.println(index);
  }
}
```

I have written the method pasted above to find the index number of the number closest to 32 in an array. But I keep getting the error " invalid variable declaration". 
I am a complete beginner and I am not able to spot what might be going wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best.

Comment: Assuming you have a class Maths defined, the code is fine.

Comment: You might want to use `java.lang.Math.abs()` instead of `Maths.abs`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)

Answer (score 1):

two things:

1. your error is just a typo = there is no Math**s** class, but `Math` or in full `java.lang.Math`
2. In logic you forgot to refresh `diff` to `newDiff` if closer element found.
   so your if statement must look like:

   ```
   if (newDiff < diff){
     diff = newDiff;
     index=i;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this with Java 8 streams:

```
public int indexOfClosestNumber(int number, int... a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .boxed()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(number - a[i])))
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

I've changed the name and signature of the method so that it's more meaningful and easy to use.

The idea of the code is that we have a range of `int`s and we want to find the minimum within that range of indexes, according to the provided comparator. In order to be able to specify a comparator to the `Stream.min` method, we need a `Stream<Integer>` instead of an `IntStream`, that's why I've used `.boxed()`. Then, the comparator works by comparing the distance of each element of the array to the provided `number`. As the `Stream.min` method returns an `Optional<Integer>`, we need to use `Optional.orElse` method with a default value (this will be returned if the provided array is empty).

To use the method above, do as follows:

```
int index = indexOfClosestNumber(32, -1, 58, 31, 16, 54);

System.out.println(index); // 2
```

Comment: I immediately thought about `ceiling` after reading the title of the question... but this looks nice also

Comment: Or `min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(number - a[i])))`

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that elements are unique in your array, it could be done with `TreeMap#ceiling`:

```
 int a[] = { -1, 58, 32, 16, 54 };
    int index = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> a[x], x -> x, (left, right) -> left, TreeMap::new))
            .ceilingEntry(32).getValue();
```

Comment: I think this supports duplicates in the array. You'll just return the first item that matches...